# Is it possible to change the text color inside the VSE by changing the source code?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I would like to know if it is possible to change the color value of a text strip made in the VSE.

The default color is white, but what if you have a background which the predominant color is white? 
Is it possible to change the text color via python or changing the source code since there is no option in the user interface?
Meaning a different solution other than to render the text with an alpha background and then change it by color correction and re-render it again.

Comment: What is to do with the "source code"?! From the question it could be understood that you want to rewrite blender's source code for changing a text color...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it directly in the VSE. In the Properties panel, scroll down to Add Strip Modifier, add a Color Balance and change the Gain.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Duane. The "Copy to Selected Strips" button is also very handy! :)

Comment: @chicOrtiz If you have several consecutive text strips, you can also combine them into a meta strip and set the modifier on that one. And I was just about to see if I can cook up an outline for the text as well, as is usually seen in subtitles. I won't promise anything, but if I do manage to get that working, I'll edit my answer to include it.

Comment: @chicOrtiz A little follow-up. I've not been able to work out outlines to the text without external postprocessing. But OTOH you never asked for it, I wanted to try anyway. ;) The best thing I managed was duplicating the text strip, Alpha Over one onto the other, enabling shadow on the lower one and giving them different colours.